# XML, XSL to HTML project

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to figure out a way to have some statistics shown for this XML/XSL project.  Is there a way to have templates in my XSL that do my computations and then reference those in the a href... section?  I find XML and XSL to be cumbersome and almost harder than a language like Java or Python.  I'd love to show stats on Vintage and Country in some decent way.  Hope all this makes sense as I'm starting to get blurry.  All day looking at Gradle and Groovy scripts then come home to hours of XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Vino</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vinoXML.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Vino</h1>
            <div class="center">
                <a href="" class="button">Vino Home</a>
                <a href="" class="button">Vino Stats by Vintage</a>
                <a href="" class="button">Vino Stats by Country</a>
            </div>
            <table class="winedetail">
                <tr>
                    <th class="name">Name</th>
                    <th class="category">Category</th>
                    <th class="variety">Variety</th>
                    <th class="vintage">Vintage</th>
                    <th class="wineregion">Wine Region</th>
                    <th class="origin">Origin</th>
                    <th class="notes">Notes</th>
                    <th class="photo">Photo</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="wine/winedetail"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="winedetail">
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </td>
        <td class="category">
            <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
        </td>
        <td class="variety">
            <xsl:value-of select="variety"/>
        </td>
        <td class="vintage">
            <xsl:value-of select="vintage"/>
        </td>
        <td class="wineregion">
            <xsl:value-of select="wineregion"/>
        </td>
        <td class="origin">
            <xsl:value-of select="origin"/>
        </td>
        <td class="notes">
            <xsl:value-of select="notes"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="~/github/XML/XML/XML_Data_DU/FinalProject/photos/{name}.jpg"
                 alt="{name}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a snapshot of the XML

```
<wine>
<winedetail>
    <name>Kenwood Jack London</name>
    <category>Red Wine</category>
    <variety>Cabernet Sauvignon</variety>
    <vintage>2013</vintage>
    <wineregion>Sonoma County</wineregion>
    <origin>USA</origin>
    <notes>
        Since our first vintage from the Jack London Ranch in 1976 it has proven itself as an outstanding producer
        of exceptional Cabernet Sauvignon. Located midway up the Eastern flanks of Sonoma Mountain it has a long
        mild growing season that creates fruit with complexity and balance. The influence of the vineyard's red
        volcanic soil and the fruity characteristics of the grapes combine to produce an outstanding, very
        distinctive Cabernet Sauvignon.
    </notes>
</winedetail>
</wine>
```

Comment: The answer is probably "yes", but before you can write any XSLT you need to know what you want your output to look like. Can you edit your question to show the expected output you want? Thank you!

Comment: So a few actually.  I'd like to have one page show a count of the Vintage by Category. @TimC